# PHP: Passing parameter by reference didn't work

Tags: php, function, variables, reference

I'm creating a function which passing parameter by reference. I just can't get return value with this code and I need your help.

```
function wow ($id, &$a, &$b)
    {
        $detail[0][0] = 1;
        $detail[0][1] = 2;
        $detail[0][2] = 3;
        $detail[0][3] = 4;

        $detail[1][0] = -1;
        $detail[1][1] = -2;
        $detail[1][2] = -3;
        $detail[1][3] = -4;

        for($i=0; $i<=$id; $i++)
        if ($detail[$i][3] == 4)
        {
            $a = $detail[$i][0];
            $a = $detail[$i][1];
            $a = $detail[$i][2];
            $a = $detail[$i][3];
        }
        else
        {
            $b = $detail[$i][0];
            $b = $detail[$i][1];
            $b = $detail[$i][2];
            $b = $detail[$i][3];
        }

    }
```

This is the way I call the function.

```
$a = $b = null;
    wow(1, $a, $b);
    echo $a[0]." ".$a[1]." ".$a[2]." ".$a[3]." ".$a[4]." ".$b[0]." ".$b[1]." ".$b[2]." ".$b[3]." ".$b[4]." ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing how arrays work:

```
    for($i=0; $i<=$id; $i++)
    if ($detail[$i][3] == 4)
    {
        $a = $detail[$i][0];
        $a = $detail[$i][1];
        $a = $detail[$i][2];
        $a = $detail[$i][3];
    }
```

Each of these statemenets is overwriting the previous one.

Try something like this:

```
    for($i=0; $i<=$id; $i++)
    if ($detail[$i][3] == 4)
    {
        $a = $detail[$i];
    }
```

That was you are copying the entire array inside the first one into `$a`.

Additionally, you set both `$a` and `$b` to null, yet only set one or the other in your function - you will always return at least a warning telling you about a null variable you are trying to echo.